Building my first ever Gutenberg block
I have created a Gutenberg block using the following command:
npx @wordpress/create-block test-block --template @wordpress/create-block-tutorial-template
Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/quick-start-guide/
Then ran npm start from within wp-content/plugins/test-block directory. Everything ran successfully. The plugin is active. But cannot find it inside the inserter.
Plugin meta:
**
 * Plugin Name:       Test Block
 * Text Domain:       test-block
 * ...
 * @package           create-block
 */

This is my first Gutenberg block!

Gutenberg recently upgraded JSX Runtime which is only compatible WP >= 6.6. See link https://make.wordpress.org/core/2024/06/06/jsx-in-wordpress-6-6/
If you update WordPress to 6.6-beta2 then it should work.
In the meantime they are figuring out about back compatibility. See comment - https://make.wordpress.org/core/2024/06/06/jsx-in-wordpress-6-6/#comment-46779
Or if you are not ready to upgrade to WP 6.6 yet, you can downgrade @wordpress/scripts to 27 version. This back compat havoc came in version 28.

I removed the template part from the npx command so that it reads @wordpress/create-block test-block. This automatically scaffolds the bolier plate with @wordpress/script version 27.9.0. Thank you for the advise :)
